# In react, how do I access state inside an action creator?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-redux, redux-thunk

My store contains an array to which I'm appending new items when the user clicks a button. The content of those items depends on a flag set elsewhere in the store.

e.g if the user has previously enabled "Setting X", the new array items should contain `{ type: 'x'}` rather than the default `{type: 'y'}`.

I understand how to dispatch an action to execute the addition of a new array item, but I can't work out how to compose that action of other parts of the state.

My questions:

1. Do I really need to be using `redux-thunk` here? I can't find a single SO answer that doesn't ultimately fall back on it.
2. I'm new at React and would like to understand why this isn't possibly by default. Is this all because the state could somehow change between the user clicking the button and the action being dispatched?
3. Is there a more obvious/hacky method I'm missing to do this? I've tried using `ownProps` in `mapDispatchToProps` but `ownProps` only appears to contain props *not* provided by `connect()` and "Setting X" *is* provided by it.

Comment: You could use the fact that each reducer is actually handling every state change to act in 2 different reducers. So you could use the same case statement in 2 reducers.

Comment: You mean create the new array item with reducer A without any `type`, but identify it somehow so a second reducer B can 'upgrade' that new array item with a `type`? That sounds like a recipe for maintenance confusion to me.

Comment: Well yes but that's the situation you are describing. Or maybe I'm missing something? Maybe if you can throw in some code we can look at it'd be easier to help :)

Comment: The flag can be the param of the action. You can read statein the component and pass it along when creating the action. You can also handle that in a parent reducer that sees everything in the subreducers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your requirement, but if you just want to update the store by some settings, you can try this:

1. Create an action to change the setting, and a reducer to save the setting in the store

   ```
   dispatch({
     type: 'CHANGE_SETTING',
     flag: X,
   })
   ```
2. With `redux-thunk`,  create another action,
   it can use `getState` to get the settings from store,

   ```
   const updateArrayBySetting = (dispatch, getState) => {
       if (getState().setting === 'X') {
           dispatch(updateArray())  // contain type 'X'
       }
       if (getState().setting === 'Y') {
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function reducer1(state = {x: true}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SOME_CHANGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        x: action.data.bool,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
function reducer2(state = {y: [1]}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SOME_CHANGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        y: [...action.data.arrayStuff],
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```